# Drawing a circle with a sector cut out in OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to draw the following shape using OpenGL ES 1.1. And well, I'm stuck, I don't really know how to go about it.

My game currently uses Android's Canvas API, which isn't hardware accelerated, so I'm rewriting it with OpenGL ES. The Canvas class has a method called drawArc which makes drawing this shape very very easy; [Canvas.drawArc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Any advice/hints on doing the same with OpenGL ES?

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void gltDrawArc(unsigned int const segments, float angle_start, float angle_stop)
{
    int i;
    float const angle_step = (angle_stop - angle_start)/segments;

    GLfloat *arc_vertices;
    arc_vertices = malloc(2*sizeof(GLfloat) * (segments+2));

    arc_vertices[0] = arc_vertices[1] = 0.

    for(i=0; i<segments+1; i++) {
        arc_vertices[2 + 2*i    ] = cos(angle_start + i*angle_step);
        arc_vertices[2 + 2*i + 1] = sin(angle_start + i*angle_step);
    }
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, arc_vertices);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, segments+2);
    free(arc_vertices);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just sampling the circle at discrete angles and drawing a `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`?

**EDIT:** Something like this will just draw a sector of a unit circle around the origin in 2D:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    for(angle=startAngle; angle<=endAngle; ++angle)
        glVertex2f(cos(angle), sin(angle));
glEnd();
```

Actually take this more as pseudocode, as `sin` and `cos` usually work on radians and I'm using degrees, but you should get the point.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by 'sample'? I have just added a bit more information above to give some more context. Edit: Thanks for the snippet, I'll go have a play with it.

Comment: @C0deAttack OpenGL cannot directly draw curved shapes, so you have to approximate them by polygonal shapes. So my above code just approximates a circle by a polygon with 360 edges, by sampling the continuous circle curve at discrete parameter values (angles). If you still don't understand, then you probably got to start at a lower and more fundamental/theoretical level of computer graphics and mathematics in general and drawing a circle is your least problem.

Comment: Just to remind newbies out there OpenGL ES doesn't support the glBegin()/glEnd() blocks. You have to create arrays.

Comment: @bad Indeed I'm a newbie in ES, but he didn't mention the intended version and I thought OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1 supports `glBegin`/`glEnd`. GLES 2.0 should be the first version to drop these. Oh, actually he mentions the version and it's indeed 1.1, so `glBegin`/`glEnd` should work (although arrays might be faster).

Comment: @christian opengl es 1.1 and 2.0 does not have glBegin/glEnd. check here from the reference: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/ and at least it is the case in iphone and android.

Comment: and btw, as I am a total newbie myself I hope no one gets offended when I call others with this name too :)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) programming so I am sure there is probably a better way to do this. But I was following the OpenGL ES 1.0 tutorial on the android developers site http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html which walks you through drawing a green triangle.  You can follow the link and you will see most of the code I used there.  I wanted to draw a circle on the triangle.  The code I added is based on the above example posted by datenwolf. And is shown in snippets below:

```
public class HelloOpenGLES10Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    // the number small triangles used to make a circle
    public int segments = 100;
    public float mAngle;
    private FloatBuffer triangleVB;
            // array to hold the FloatBuffer for the small triangles
    private FloatBuffer [] segmentsArray = new FloatBuffer[segments];


    private void initShapes(){

                   .
                   .
                   .

        // stuff to draw holes in the board      
        int i = 0;
        float angle_start = 0.0f;
        float angle_stop = 2.0f * (float) java.lang.Math.PI;
        float angle_step = (angle_stop - angle_start)/segments;

        for(i=0; i<segments; i++) {
            float[] holeCoords;
            FloatBuffer holeVB;
            holeCoords = new float [ 9 ];
            // initialize vertex Buffer for triangle  
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            ByteBuffer vbb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(holeCoords.length * 4); 
            vbb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());// use the device hardware's native byte order
            holeVB = vbb2.asFloatBuffer();  // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer

            float x1 = 0.05f * (float) java.lang.Math.cos(angle_start + i*angle_step);
            float y1 = 0.05f * (float) java.lang.Math.sin(angle_start + i*angle_step);
            float z1 = 0.1f;
            float x2 = 0.05f * (float) java.lang.Math.cos(angle_start + i+1*angle_step);
            float y2 = 0.05f * (float) java.lang.Math.sin(angle_start + i+1*angle_step);
            float z2 = 0.1f;
            holeCoords[0] = 0.0f;
            holeCoords[1] = 0.0f;
            holeCoords[2] = 0.1f;
            holeCoords[3] = x1;
            holeCoords[4] = y1;
            holeCoords[5] = z1;
            holeCoords[6] = x2;
            holeCoords[7] = y2;
            holeCoords[8] = z2;
            holeVB.put(holeCoords);    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
            holeVB.position(0);            // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
            segmentsArray[i] = holeVB;
        }            
    }

    .
    .
    .


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        .
        .
        .
        // Draw hole
        gl.glColor4f( 1.0f - 0.63671875f, 1.0f - 0.76953125f, 1.0f - 0.22265625f, 0.0f);
        for ( int i=0; i<segments; i++ ) {
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, segmentsArray[i]);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }

}
```

[image: Here's a screen shot in the emulator]